# Languages of Microsoft Office

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, language-pack

I am in France, and I just bought the CD `Microsoft Excel 2010`.

While installing it, there was no option to choose the language. After the installation, the language is in French which matches the language of my Windows (which is in French)... But it is NOT what I want, I would like the Excel to be in English.

I set all what i can in the `option` as follows, but the menus are buttons are still in French, it is because there is not English in the second window to choose.

So, do I have to pay extra money and buy the language package? Is it just because my Windows is in French, Office can't display in English?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office (and many other software) has language-specific versions that are independent of the OS language. Judging by your screenshot, you have purchased a French-only version of Excel since in the section to change interface language you have only OS default & French.

As an individual, you can get Excel in any other language semi-legally only by finding the installer package in the needed language and using your license key with it. The gray area is that you'll likely have to go to Torrents and Microsoft doesn't officially acknowledge that licenses can be used on any language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this would be the issue, but do you have English installed under Windows itself?

Go to the Control Panel, type "lang" in the search box. Choose "Change Display Language".

On the Keyboards & Languages tab, the second section is "Display Language", make sure that you have English installed there.

Sorry that these instructions are in English, hopefully you will be better at translating to French than me!

Comment: Thanks... there isn't the second section "Display Language"... It seems that I have to buy it...